# How to find the maximum probability of satisfying the conditions in all combinations of arrays

Tags: python, algorithms

for example, I got a list of tokens and each token's number of characters(length) is

```
length = [2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

and here is the list of each token's probability of [not insert a linefeed, insert a linefeed] after the token

```
prob =  [[9.9978e-01, 2.2339e-04],  [9.9995e-01, 4.9344e-05],  [0.9469, 0.0531],  
         [9.9994e-01, 5.8422e-05],  [0.9964, 0.0036],  [9.9991e-01, 9.4295e-05],  
         [9.9980e-01, 1.9620e-04],  [1.0000e+00, 5.2492e-08],  [9.9998e-01, 1.8293e-05],  
         [9.9999e-01, 5.1220e-06],  [1.0000e+00, 3.9795e-06],  [0.0142, 0.9858]]
```

and the result for the probabilies is

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

which means inserting a linefeed after the last token.
The whole length of this line is 21, and I would like to have a maximum of 20 characters per line.
In that case, I have to insert one (in this example, maybe more in other situations) more linefeed to make sure every line has 20 characters at most.
In this example, the best answer is

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

since the 3rd token gets the highest probability of inserting a linefeed.

My thought is to make all combinations of these probabilities.(Multiply them instead of adding) I got 12 tokens in this example, each token gets its 0-1 Classification Probability, so there are 2^12 kinds of combination. And I use the binary sequence to record every situation (since it's a 0-1 Classification Problem)and store them in a dictionary in format of [binary sequence, the combination of probabilities].

```
    for i in range(nums):
        num *= 2
    numx = bin(num)
    for i in range(num):
        numx = bin(numx - 1)
        str1 = numx.encode('ascii').decode('ascii')
        str1 = str1.lstrip('0b')
        probb = 1
        for k in range(len(str1)):
            x = str1[k]
            if int(x) == 0:          # [0, 1]
                probb *= prob_task2[k][0]
            else:
                probb *= prob_task2[k][1]
        dic[str1] = probb
```

Then I want to sort all kinds of combination, and search the possible result from high to low.
I make two loops for making all combinations. And another two loops for searching the combinations from top to low in order to meet the restriction of characters. But I got some troubles with the efficiency, since once there are 40 tokens, I have to count 2^40 kinds of combinations.

I am not good at algorithms, so I do want to ask is there an efficient way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Let $z_i \in \{0,1\}$ be the binary decision of whether to predict a linefeed or not. Given the probability of a linefeed $p^1$, and the probability of no linefeed $p^0$, you seem to describe a maximum likelihood objective function of the form
$$
\max \log \prod_i \left( p^1 z_i + p^0 (1 - z_i) \right),
$$

where your example has $p^1$ = `[0.00022339, 4.9344e-5, 0.0531, 5.8422e-5, 0.0036, 9.4295e-5, 0.0001962, 5.2492e-8, 1.8293e-5, 5.122e-6, 3.9795e-6, 0.9858]`, and
$p^0$ = `[0.99978, 0.99995, 0.9469, 0.99994, 0.9964, 0.99991, 0.9998, 1.0, 0.99998, 0.99999, 1.0, 0.0142]`. Note that I added the logarithmic transformation for concavity; it doesn't change the optimal solution set, but allows you to deploy disciplined convex optimization software [1].

The *maximum characters per line* constraint can be represented as a set of cover inequalities of the form:
$$
\sum_{i \in C} z_i \geq 1,\quad \forall C,
$$

where a cover, $C$, is defined as an index range where the total length exceeds the limit, i.e., for which
$$
\sum_{i \in C} \mbox{length[i]} > L.
$$

The cover inequality hence state that there must be at least one linefeed in each cover. In your example you had `L=20` and `length = [2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]`, and there would thus only be one cover; namely the full index range from start to end. Hence, the corresponding formulation for this particular example would only have one cover inequality simply summing over all $z_i$ variables. In the general case, you would have to generate all covers by looping over every possible start index and find the corresponding end index at which the line length exceeded the limit.

[1] If you wanted to use conic optimization software such as MOSEK, for example, you would rewrite it as follows:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\max &\log \prod_i u_i,&\mbox{where }u_i = p^1 z_i + p^0 (1 - z_i)\\
&= \sum_i \log u_i,\\
&= \sum_i v_i,&\mbox{where }u_i \geq \exp(v_i).\\
\end{array}
$$
and thus get a linear objective function and one [exponential cone](https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/expo.html) per index $i$.